# make a pagination with variable total page number

Tags: reactjs

I have a one data list that could have variable length and the maximum length is 20.
I want to make a format for pagination UI, like

like this

```
< 1 2 3 4 5 … 20 > (a default format) 
< 1 … 5 6 7 8 9 … 15 > (a format when the last page >= 15) 
< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 > (a format when the last page <= 7)
< 1 2 > (a format when the last page = 2, last page is shorter than 5)
```

I want to make it with if else or switch case but don’t know how to do it
here is my code

```
let pageNum = [];
let total == datalist.length
const lastPage = Math.ceil(total / listPerPage);
const firstPage = Math.ceil((total / listPerPage) -  (total / listPerPage - 1));
switch (true) {
    case total === 0:
      pageNum.push(0);
      break;
     default:
      pageNum = [
        firstPage,
        "...",
        3, 4, 5,
        "...",
        lastPage,
      ];
  }
```

How can i do it with switch case of if else

Comment: What do you want for 8-14?  There is no condition stated for that.

Comment: same with 1 ~ 15

Comment: This requires more work than you're letting on.  To answer your question properly we would have to invent all the logic for tracking which page you're currently on and how that displays.   Unless you have that defined somewhere, in which case you might want to include it.